# Titles for elements in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add some description before(after) textfield or other elements in python tkinter but do not know how.
How can I do it?

Comment: Please show us what you done so far, or atleast describe to us your current thoughts on how to do this

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wN9vwCBG  here is my code Johan

Comment: I need a description for this fields in the bottom of each but i do not know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Label

```
root = Tk()
L1 = Label(root, text="Your description")
T1 = Text(root)
L1.pack(side=LEFT)
T1.pack(side=RIGHT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are no other ways to do it? Maybe some attribute for textfield or other element?

Comment: Text widget does not have any such attribute. If you want such a Widget then you need to create your own class that inherits from Text and contain a label and the text box

Comment: No problems, glad to help. If you have been helped by my answer please accept it and wote it up